# How to set up an endpoint on Cloud Shell (Node.js)

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, express, google-cloud-endpoints

For the past week or so, I've been learning Node.js, and I would like to have some endpoint on my Google Cloud account. I've been using it to learn and test, it's very useful. However, I would like to have a url for these endpoints.

Currently, I'm just wanting to run the below code, and the url it gives me is:

https://8080-dot-3465512-dot-devshell.appspot.com/

This is obviously not the correct one, although it does return 'hello'.

Is there a way for me to find the host URL so I can use this as an endpoint?

```
var express = require('express');

var app = express();

app.get('/', function(req,res){
    res.send("hello");
});

console.log("begin");

app.listen(8080);
```

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Do you want to give a specific domain to your endpoint, for example, `www.myapp.com`?

Comment: This is a tutorial on how to get started with [Cloud Endpoints for NodeJs](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/get-started-app-engine#node). Is this what you want? Please answer

Answer (score 1):

You usually receive an URL like that (`_https://8080-dot-3465512-dot-devshell.appspot.com/_`) when you deploy your Node project locally in the [Cloud Shell](https://cloud.google.com/shell/) and use the [Web Preview button](https://cloud.google.com/shell/docs/using-web-preview).

If you want to set up a NodeJS Endpoint with Google Cloud Endpoints you have to follow [this steps](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/get-started-app-engine#task_list):

1. Set up a Cloud Platform project, install required software, and create an App Engine app. See [Before you begin](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/get-started-app-engine#before-you-begin).
2. Download the sample code:

`git clone https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/nodejs-docs-samples`

and then `cd nodejs-docs-samples/endpoints/getting-started`

3. Configure the `openapi-appengine.yaml` file, which is used to configure Endpoints with this content:

   ```
   swagger: "2.0"
   info:
     description: "A simple Google Cloud Endpoints API example."
     title: "Endpoints Example"
     version: "1.0.0"
   host: "YOUR-PROJECT-ID.appspot.com"
   ```

   See that you have to substitute: `YOUR-PROJECT-ID...` in the last line
4. Deploy the Endpoints configuration to create a Cloud Endpoints service with this command: `gcloud endpoints services deploy openapi-appengine.yaml`
5. Create a backend to serve the API and deploy the API. [See Deploying the API backend.](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/get-started-app-engine#deploy_backend)
6. Send a request to the API. [See Sending a request to the API](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/get-started-app-engine#send_request).
7. Track API activity. [See Tracking API activity](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/get-started-app-engine#track_api).

8.Avoid incurring charges to your Google Cloud Platform account. See Clean up.

I tried to summarize it but there are times when you have to follow the links. Hope this helps